# Clarification of steps while generating of OpenCV libraries using CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, cmake, dynamically-generated

I have generated the OpenCV libraries using CMake a couple of times using tutorials available online, albeit without completely understanding the process. Here is the process that I follow

1. Configure CMake to build the OpenCV binaries (eg with QT, TBB, without CUDA, OpenCL etc)
2. Generate the binaries using CMake
3. The folder where the binaries are built has a number of `.sln` files. I open the file `OpenCV.sln` and run the project `ALL_BUILD` for both Debug and Release configurations.
4. There is a new folder created. `bin` which contains the libraries (both `.lib` and `.dll` for the release and debug versions.
5. (Optional) Sometimes I have also build the project named `INSTALL` (in the same solution), just out of curiosity. I noticed that it creates another folder, that contains the library files in almost the same pattern as the prebuilt libraries that come with the OpenCV package. Interestingly, my programs in MSVC or Qt work equally well if I link with either the libraries in the `install` folder or the `bin`/`lib` folder.

My questions are

1. What is the function of the  `install` solution?
2. How are the libraries generated by the `install` solution different from the ones found in the `bin` and `lib` folders?
3. Why is the `install` solution not built when the `ALL_BUILD` solution is built

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What is the function of the  `install` solution?

It packages/collects the build output into a portable set of libraries and *headers* that you know you can move around in your pc, or to another machine.

> 2. How are the libraries generated by the `install` solution different from the ones found in the `bin` and `lib` folders?

They are not. You have probably built first shared and then (by reconfiguring with cmake) static libraries, but than the target install only installs the one you have currently selected (in your cmake-gui?)

> 3. Why is the `install` solution not built when the `ALL_BUILD` solution is built

`install` is a special target for cmake. In fact, by default `install` triggers `all` and only actually executes when `all` has successfully terminated, but the viceversa is not true.

Comment: 1. Infact, the include directory, (containing the `opencv` and `opencv2` directories) is not generated if I do not run the `install` solution.

Comment: 2. No I did not reconfigure the binaries using CMake. I built the `ALL_BUILD` project followed by the `INSTALL` project. (the `INSTALL` project is in the CMakeTargets folder though) Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?
3. By `all` you mean `ALL_BUILD`? if yes then shouldn't `install`  run **automatically** after `ALL_BUILD`? (unless not required, which does not seem the case since running `install` generates the header files

Comment: @user3079474 As I said, it's the install target that creates the portable header collection. Therefore I don't understand your first comment. Regarding the other comment, the building process doesn't include installation, while the vice-versa is true, as to be able to install you first need to build your binaries. Note that the headers already exists, and the target `install` simply collects and copy them in the installation directory.

Comment: So one final thing, if the libraries generated by `install` solution and the binaries built by the OpenCV solution are the same, then why the need to have two different solutions for the sake of portability? (I checked, even the size of the libraries are exactly the same). I get that their functionality is same, but then what is the difference between them?

Comment: @user3079474 I don't think in this case there are 2 solutions. When building,you generate libraries that are put in this build/bin directory. When installing,you build and generate libraries that are put in this build/bin directory, and then copy them in the installation directory, together with the headers. If you run install immediately after a build, it takes no time. If you run install from a clean build,it takes all the time necessary to build. And if afterwards you try to build, there won't be any work to do. Again, the purpose of install is "packaging" the created libraries and headers.